# How to find all .NET Core/.NET 6-incompatible members in the solution, with the actual usage info?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, migration, roslyn

I have a big project on .NET Framework 4.8, and I would like to find all usages of .NET Core/.NET 6-incompatible members in the code.

There are some tools from Microsoft but, unfortunately, they don't provide the information about the actual place in the source code where an incompatible member is used.

For example, there is [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) but it works with assemblies by using `System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader` inside to retrieve all incompatible `MemberInfo` used in the assembly. So it outputs a list of incompatible types and members used in the project but has no information about where they are used, or how many usages there are.

I also tried [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) hoping that its `analyze` command would help but it doesn't support a lot of .NET Framework types and scenarios. For example, it missed a `new AppDomainSetup()` call or calls to any ASP.NET Web Forms classes like `System.Web.UI.Control` that .NET Portability Analyzer reported as non-compatible. It seems that it knows only about ASP.NET MVC/Windows Forms/WPF-specific things.

I am trying to retrieve this detailed information to be able to track the progress of our migration. So I would like to run this kind of analysis automatically in the CI/CD pipeline, retrieving the list of incompatible usages, and comparing it with the previous report to get a clear picture of whether we have new incompatible calls added by a new pull request.

Any suggestions on how I can get this kind of information would be much appreciated.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to get the report from .NET Portability Analyzer, iterate through all incompatible types&members, and use Roslyn to find all usages in the source code, but this solution involves a lot of work.

Comment: Try the [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview).

Comment: @PauloMorgado Thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried it, and it didn't help. Added a section with more details on what went wrong with this tool.

Comment: AppDomains are not available in .NET (Core) and Web Forma are not available in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I know that but it is not my question; AppDomains and ASP.NET Web Forms are just examples. The question is how to collect this information automatically, on per-build basis, without missing any unsupported types (which .NET Upgrade Assistant misses).

Comment: I think the answer here is the tools that you are using are the tools that you should be using, they're just falling short. It's possible there's a bug causing it to not catch the things you're looking for.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I checked the source code of .NET Upgrade Assistant, and its implementation is very basic and immature. It uses Roslyn to find only some hard-coded namespaces and members; that's the reason why it doesn't find everything. [Here's a good example](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/blob/v0.2.0/src/extensions/default/analyzers/Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.CSharp.Analyzers/UsingSystemWebAnalyzer.cs). As for the .NET Portability Annalyzer, its Reflection-based nature stops it from finding usages; Reflection API doesn't provide this type of information.